# Calling a Javascript function at the end of a 'setInterval'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

Before posting this I've browsed some existing topics but couldn't get anything helpful, I tried some things to fix this but it failed.

I'm developing a website, and today I wanted to code a basic dark mode switch in Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function switchWhite() {
    document.getElementById("body").className = "";
    document.getElementById("menubar").className = "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light";
}

function switchDark() {
    document.getElementById("body").className = "dark";
    document.getElementById("menubar").className = "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark";
}

function triggerSwitch() {
    if ( document.getElementById("body").className.match("dark") ) {
        switchWhite();
    } else {
        switchDark();
    }
}
</script>

<button onclick="triggerSwitch()">Switch Mode</button>
```

This works just fine but there is an auto-refresh on the website, which is triggered every 30 seconds and which refreshes only specific blocs (like menubar) :

```
<script>
setInterval(function()
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menubar_refresh").load(document.URL + " #menubar");
    });
}, 30000);
</script>
```

Which also works fine, but I cannot mix these two features because once I switch to dark mode theme, after 30 seconds (when the auto-refresh is triggered), it gets back to light mode (the original state of the page).

Though is this normal, so I tried to put the dark mode back right after the bloc refreshes, like this :

```
<script>
setInterval(function()
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menubar_refresh").load(document.URL + " #menubar");
    });
    switchDark(); // here
}, 30000);
</script>
```

It simply doesn't work, the bloc (and only this bloc, not the whole page) still gets back to the original state (light).
I've noticed that it switches to dark mode for a few milliseconds, and gets back to the original state.
I thought that the `switchDark();` call is executed at first, even before the whole function finishes, in a way that the dark mode is set and **then** the bloc is refreshed.

So I tried setting a variable to block the execution of `switchDark();` call before everything else finished executing, but the result is the same, which makes me think that my hypothesis is wrong.

Could you please help me to figure out what the problem is here ?
I can add more code snippets if you need them.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is *asynchronous* so you need to modify any new content in the complete callback.

Something like:

```
$("#menubar_refresh").load(document.URL + " #menubar", switchDark);
```

Or more verbose version:

```
$("#menubar_refresh").load(document.URL + " #menubar", function(){
    // new content now exists
    // add logic as to which theme method to call
    if(isDark){
      switchDark();
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, this works. I don't know why I didn't think about it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm in agreement with the answer by @charlietfl. But there is a flaw in your code due to misunderstanding and misinterpretation of javascript's event handler asynchronous nature.

The code in question is this:

```javascript
<script> 
    setInterval(function() { 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#menubar_refresh").load(document.URL + " #menubar"); }); 
            switchDark(); // here 
        }, 
    30000);
</script>
```

You are using `$(document).ready` inadvertently as an `if` statement not as an event handler. Apparently, your code says *after 30secs, if the document is ready, refresh the document and switch to a dark theme*. But actually, your code means *after 30secs, attach the ready state change handler to `document`. In this handler, asynchronously refresh the page and [immediately] switch to a dark theme*.

Now, here lies your problem:

1. Though there is practically one, there is no 'absolute' guarantee that the `document` will be ready after 30secs. Consequently, your code setup isn't one that actually executes after 30secs.
2. There is no practical and absolute guarantee that the page will refresh *completely* before `switchDark()` executes. Why? The code for refreshing is asynchronous. Consequently, your `switchDark()` function almost never executes as you expect it to (though it always executes) since you expect it to use code from the newly loaded page.

A better and more meaningful code setup is to include `setInterval` inside `$(document).ready` handler and use a callback with the `load()` method for any code you want executed after the `load()` method.

```js
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        setInterval(function() { 
            $("#menubar_refresh").load(document.URL + " #menubar", function() {
                switchDark(); // here 
            }); 
        }, 30000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `load()` does not return a deferred object

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected that. My major point is the position of `$('document').ready` in the question.